# Adding Dynamic Input Field Within Nested "Correct" Category Group

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a dynamic form where you can add multiple categories and within those categories add multiple input fields

states (is there a better way in doing the states?):

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState([{ value: null }]);
const [group, setGroups] = useState([{ id: null, cat: null, items: [] }]);
```

functions:

```
// This is to add multiple group of fields.
const handleAddGroup = () => {
  const values = [...group];
  console.log("values", values);
  values.push({ id: null, cat: null, items: [] });
  setGroups(values);
};

// this is where I'm having trouble,
// it doesn't add the new field within the respected category group.
const handleAddField = (i) => {
  const newSetOfField = [...group[i].items];
  newSetOfField.push({ value: null });
  setFields(newSetOfField);
};
```

code:

```
<Segment>
  <Header content="Create item" />
  <Button primary onClick={() => handleAddGroup()}>
    Add Group
  </Button>
  <Form>
    {group.map((group, groupIdx) => {
      return (
        <Segment key={`${group}-${groupIdx}`}>
          <Button primary onClick={() => handleAddField(groupIdx)}>
            +
          </Button>
          <Form.Field>
            <input
              value={group.cat}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Category title"
              onChange={(e) => handleChangeCategory(groupIdx, e)}
            />
          </Form.Field>
          {group.items.map((field, fieldIdx) => {
            return (
              <>
                <Form.Field key={`${field}-${fieldIdx}`}>
                  <input
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeField(fieldIdx, e)}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Item title"
                  />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button onClick={() => handleRemoveField(fieldIdx)}>
                  X
                </Button>
              </>
            );
          })}
          <Button onClick={() => handleRemoveGroup(groupIdx)}>
            Remove Group
          </Button>
        </Segment>
      );
    })}
  </Form>
</Segment>
```

I'm able to use `handleAddGroup()` to populate multiple groups of fields. Image shown:

[image]

Those + buttons supposed to add input fields under the category title input field.

Comment: What I may suggest is have a top level component such FormConfig and have the whole configuration object there, which contains all the field's metadata, and pass that config property downwards and reading it to create the UI for fields and Segments.

Comment: @Asutosh i think that sounds like a good idea, anyway to show some code? :) thank you

Comment: it will take time to build a component, will see If I can build once I get some time.In the mean time take inspiration from this : https://medium.com/curofy-engineering/dynamic-forms-with-react-js-d25d7c4f53d1

Comment: @Asutosh thank you for the reference!